# Mass renaming directories to move the year from end to beginning

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, regex, batch-rename

I am currently struggling with some music folders. I once decided to name them following the pattern: `artist - album - year`. I realized today that this wasn't a clever move and want now to name my directories following the pattern: `year - artist - album` as they will then show up in ascending order when listed.

I started doing the renaming by hand but, with roughly 700 folders, there has to be a simpler way ; I tried using `gprename` but I'm not so good at regex and bash scripting...

Is there anyone who could help me spare my poor fingertips ?

Some examples:

```
Aes Dana - Memory Shell - 2004 
Anja Schneider & GummiHz - Back To Back (Remixes Part 2) - 2009
```

would become

```
2004 - Aes Dana - Memory Shell
2009 - Anja Schneider & GummiHz - Back To Back (Remixes Part 2)
```

EDIT: Some artist and album names have special characters like `And.Id` or `Kool & The Gang`. Though every directory has  `-` as separator.

Comment: You do know how to edit the question, so why don't you add that to the question? Also, do any of the album or artist names have `-` in them?

Comment: Is the name arranged by the "-" delimiter by definition, and does it possibly occur elsewhere in the name?

Comment: I tend to ls the source folders redirecting to a text file, then use vim. I create a macro to create a second parameter for each line with the relevant components of the source folder in the correct order, then use another macro to put mv at the start of each line. I might even go so far as to take a copy of the folder structure first in case I made a mess of/lost folders.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming you have access to perl `rename` (generally available in Ubuntu -  thanks to @Serg for clarifying the difference. If in doubt, call `/usr/bin/rename` and you should get the right one), you could use:

```
rename -n 's/(.*) - (\d{4})\//$2 - $1/' */
```

Remove `-n` after testing to actually rename the directories. This assumes all the albums date between 1000 and 9999. Probably reasonable...

#### Explanation

- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`
- `(.*)` save any number of any characters to reference as `$1` later
- `(\d{4})\/` save four digits at the end of the line to reference as `$2` later.
- `*/` match all directories (not files - thanks to @muru for help!)

Comment: Maybe do `*/` to only match directories.

Comment: @muru it seems not to work! What am I doing stupidly?

Comment: What did you run and what happened?

Comment: `rename -n 's/(.*) - ([0-9]{4})$/$2 - $1/' */` and nothing returns @muru

Comment: There are directories there, right?

Comment: yes, most certainly

Comment: There are two different programs called `rename`.  This answer assumes the Perl `rename`.  This is fine, as nobody actually *wants* the other one, as it is much less capable - but it's important to point out, in answers that use the Perl `rename`, that you might have the other one and then the answer won't work.

Comment: @zwol thanks, I edited - but I've always had perl rename in Ubuntu - where can I find out which systems have it and which do not?

Comment: @Zanna i thin what they refer  to is the fact that some shells like `mksh` have a built-in called `rename`. It is sufficient to replace it with full path or call `prename` to call the Perl rename

Comment: @Zanna Found this interesting bit: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229248/85039  **TL;DR**: The `rename` isn't "sometimes called `prename`" but apparently they're two "branches" of the same script, one that isn't maintained by Debian, and the other one that is.  So yeah . . . it's a whole lot of mess - some shells have their own `rename`, perl package has its own `rename`, and debian itself provides separate package

Comment: @Zanna I was thinking of the program referred to as `rename.ul` in http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/21167

Answer (score 6):

Simple Python script can do such job:

```
$ tree
.
├── Aes Dana - Memory Shell - 2004
├── Anja Schneider & GummiHz - Back To Back (Remixes Part 2) - 2009
└── rename_dirs.py

2 directories, 1 file
$ ./rename_dirs.py */
$ tree
.
├── 2004 - Aes Dana  -  Memory Shell 
├── 2009 - Anja Schneider & GummiHz  -  Back To Back (Remixes Part 2) 
└── rename_dirs.py
```

Script contents:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from shutil import move;
import sys

for i in sys.argv[1:] :
    parts = i[:-1].split('-')
    year = parts[-1].strip()
    new_name = year + " - " + " - ".join(parts[:-1]).strip()
    move(i,new_name)
```

#### How this works:

- The main trick is that we execute script from the same directory where targets reside. We also pass `*/` to provide only directories as arguments to the script
- The script iterates over all command-line arguments, breaking down each filename into list of strings at `-` character. New filename is constructed out of parts we extracted.
- `move()` function from `shutils` module is what actually renames the directories

Note the usage: `./rename_dirs.py */`